# Combine Two different Array List and sort based on time

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have Two Diffrent `ArrayList` lets say:

```
ArrayList<model_tasks_pending> Tasks = new ArrayList<model_tasks_pending>();
ArrayList<model_task> data = new ArrayList<model_task>();
```

Now i want combine this two array list to one and access each data in it.
This is what i have tried,

```
 private List<Object> Data = new ArrayList<>();
 Data.addAll(Tasks);
 Data.addAll(data);
```

This able to get all data into new List. But how can i access data in it? Lets say i want access `get_creat_on()` in `Tasks`

```
Data.get(0).get_creat_on()
```

but showing error `cannot resolve get_creat_on()`

Also after combine both `Arraylist` I want sort them based on time. I have `_time` object in both `Arraylist` and it return time like this format  `08:33 AM`. Any guild on how to achieve this ?

Modal Class:

**model_task.java**

```
public class model_task {
    int _id;
    String _title;
    String _body;
    String _time;

    public String get_time() {
            return _time;
        }
    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }
    public String get_title() {
        return _title;
    } 
    public String get_body() {
        return _body;
    }
}
```

**model_tasks_pending.java**

```
 public class model_tasks_pending{
        int _id;
        String _title;
        String _creat_on;
        String _time;

    public String get_time() {
            return _time;
        }
    public String get_creat_on() {
        return _creat_on;
    }
    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String get_title() {
        return _title;
    }

    public String get_body() {
        return _body;
    }
}
```

Comment: And the reason you think that including the error message is not important is...

Comment: sorry Edited question

Comment: Ah.  You really shouldn't be combining list types like that.  Why can't they remain separate?

Comment: can you possibly give an example then? i have to create new modal class with all data in it?

Comment: What about a class with two different lists in it?

Comment: You can't combine two Lists that are of two different types (unless they share a common base type, the you use that). If you need to combine the attributes of these two classes into a single one, then I'd suggest creating a new class that has the fields you want from both, and creating a List of these new objects. Or, create an interface/base class that encapsulates the methods you want to see shared between these two classes, and create a list of those.

Comment: Possible create a interface (having common methods in it) which is implemented by both the model classes. Use generics to have interface as the generic for ArrayList.

Comment: and how about sorting based on time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First : please follow [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).
Classes should start with an uppercase and variable with a lowercase.
Besides `_` is allowed but not advised.

---

About your question.

Storing instances of specific classes in a `List` of `Object` defeats the purposes of using generics.

If you want store and sort both instances of `model_tasks_pending` and `model_tasks`, you should reason in terms of interface.
Introduce a common interface with all required methods and make these classes implement it.

In this way you could replace :

```
 private List<Object> Data = new ArrayList<>();
```

by :

```
 private List<MyModelTask> Data = new ArrayList<>();
```

where `MyModelTask` is the common interface.

In this way you could access to any method defined in `MyModelTask` and you could sort `MyModelTask` by defining a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and more specifically  `Comparator<MyModelTask>` if you want to sort instances of both classes.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly i have to create a interface class MyModelTask and implement both class

Comment: You name it as you want but yes the idea is there.  About `get_creat_on()`, that is only defined in `model_tasks_pending`, you have several options to implement it in the class that doesn't have it actually : returning null, a default value or even adding a method in the interface to identify the type of instances, etc... But as you don't give details about how it should be valued, it is hard to propose one solution rather than another.

Comment: Both class have _time which will return time in specific format. i want sort newly created list based on that time.

Comment: So for the sort you should have no problem as both classes have a `have _time` field. You are welcome :)

Comment: can you possibly give an example for that?

Comment: To sort on the get_time() method you can do  : `List<MyModelTask> myModelTaskList = new ArrayList<>();...Collections.sort(myModelTaskList, Comparator.comparing(MyModelTask::get_time));`